# Loop for single bytes

Tags: python, micropython

Im have a problem in loop for single bytes and send via uart in micropython.

```
c = b'\x00\x00\x0c\x00'
for b in c:
    uart_gps.write(b)
```

Error:

```
File "<stdin>", line 3, in <module>
TypeError: object with buffer protocol required
```

Comment: Please update your question with the full error traceback.

Comment: What happens when you just do `uart_gps.write(c)`?

Comment: @mkrieger1 It will work, but I want to send as single bytes.

Comment: What's the difference between sending all bytes at once and sending each byte separately in a loop?